# How do I integrate .filter() in Taffydb?

Tags: taffydb

The following TaffyDB script successfully outputs the entire database:

```
db().each(function (name){
var bodyType=(name["bodyType"]);
var category=(name["category"]);
var name2=(name["name2"]);
var photo=(name["photo"]);
var resource=(name["resource"]);
var caption=(name["caption"]);
output = document.getElementById("display");
output.innerHTML+="<div class='segment'><p class='title'>" + bodyType + ": " + name2 + "</p>" +
"<img class='pic' src='" + photo + "' width='150px'>" +
"<p class='caption'>" + caption + "</p>" +
"<p class='more'><a href='" + resource + "'>More</a></p></div>";
});
```

My question is about how to filter the contents. The site has this code:

```
db().filter({column:value});
```

**How do I change the top code to integrate it?**

```
db().filter({bodyType:buggy});
```

This does not work:

```
db().each(function (name){
var bodyType=(name["bodyType"]);
var category=(name["category"]);
var name2=(name["name2"]);
var photo=(name["photo"]);
var resource=(name["resource"]);
var caption=(name["caption"]);
db().filter({bodyType:buggy});
output = document.getElementById("display");
output.innerHTML+="<div class='segment'><p class='title'>" + bodyType + ": " + name2 + "</p>" +
"<img class='pic' src='" + photo + "' width='150px'>" +
"<p class='caption'>" + caption + "</p>" +
"<p class='more'><a href='" + resource + "'>More</a></p></div>";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line this way:

```
db({bodyType:"Buggy"}).each(function (name){
```